# Show sibling pages in sidebar with featured image thumbnail

Tags: wordpress, siblings

I need to be able to show, in the sidebar, a list of linked sibling pages along with their featured image. I'm lost. I know enough php to be able to copy, paste, and modify. Here's the code I'm using to show the sibling pages. I cannot figure out how to show the featured images. I gather I need to attack this from another approach, I'm just now sure where to go from here.

```
<?php
global $post;
$current_page_parent = ( $post->post_parent ? $post->post_parent : $post->ID );

wp_list_pages( array(
     'title_li' => '',
     'child_of' => $current_page_parent,
     'depth' => '1' )
);
?>
```